# How can I test if a number belongs to a list in a query ? C# EP

Tags: c#, database, linq

I have this query :

```
int[] numbers = { 5, 4, 1, 3, 9, 8, 6, 7, 2, 0 };    
var queryError = from error in db.errors
                 //where error.battery_id == numbers 
                 select error;
```

And i would like to test in the where clause if a number (error.battery_id) belongs to a list and then, select the right errors.

Thanks !

Comment: What is your Linq provider?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Contains` t check if element is present in array or not

```
 var queryError = from error in db.errors
             where numbers.Contains(error.battery_id)
             select error;
```

Comment: I have this error :( : 'int[]' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.ParallelEnumerable.Contains<TSource>(System.Linq.ParallelQuery<TSou‌​rce>, TSource)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: @user2076231 Then what is the type of `battery_id`? It appears not to be `int`.

Comment: Add using `System.Linq` to your namespace

Comment: @RajeevKumar The extension method was found, but the signature wasn't right. EDIT: No, sorry, I think you may be right, it picks the extension from `ParallelEnumerable`. NEW EDIT: `ParallelEnumerable` is also in `System.Linq` namespace, so he's probably not missing a `using` after all,

Comment: It says (int? error.battery_id). What the question mark means ?

Comment: `battery_id` should be integer type

Comment: If i cast (int) before battery_id, it works. But i really want to understand why there is a question mark

Comment: @user2076231 See [Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx).

Comment: When i put my mouse on the "error.battery_id" in:                    where numbers.Contains(error.battery_id)

Comment: The question mark means that the variable is of type Nullable<int> - i.e. it can also store null as well as an integer (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx). I assume this is because an error may not have a battery_id and then it depends on what behaviour you want. One safe way to do this might be to write `where number.Contains(error.battery_id ?? -1)` so that any null values are converted to -1, and won't match any of your array. If all errors must have a battery_id, then there might be an error in your data definition (perhaps the table has a null column?)

Comment: @user2076231 The `?` Means it's a _nullable_ integer. It might be an integer (`.HasValue`) or `null`. If it is `null`, will you allow it in your query? You may change `numbers` from `int[]` into `int?[]`.

Comment: int? is meant for Nullable<int>.

Comment: Ok,thank you. But now, I have another problem. When I do this errorList = queryError.ToList(); it says  : LINQ to Entities don't recognise the method « Boolean Contains(System.Object) », so it cant be translate. How can i get my results ?

Comment: Try something like 'where error.battery_id != null && numbers.Contains(error.battery_id.Value)'

Answer (score 3):

```
var queryError = from error in db.errors
                 where numbers.Contains(error.battery_id)
                 select error;
```